# How to find Hadoop hdfs directory on my system?

Tags: linux, azure, hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-data-platform

How to find Hadoop HDFS directory on my system?
I need this to run following command -

```
hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal <local-dir> <hdfs-dir>
```

In this command I don't knon my hdfs-dir.

Not sure if its helpful or not but I ran following command and got this output -

```
 hdfs dfs -ls
-rw-r--r--   3 popeye hdfs  127162942 2016-04-01 19:47 .
```

In hdfs-site.xml, I found following entry -

```
<property>
      <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
      <value>/hadoop/hdfs/data</value>
      <final>true</final>
</property>
```

I tried to run following command but it gives error -

```
[root@sandbox try]# hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal 1987.csv /hadoop/hdfs/data
copyFromLocal: `/hadoop/hdfs/data': No such file or directory
```

FYI - I am doing all this on hortonworks sandbox on azure server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your approach is wrong or may be understanding is wrong

`dfs.datanode.data.dir`, is where you want to store your data blocks

If you type `hdfs dfs -ls /` you will get list of directories in hdfs. Then you can transfer files from local to hdfs using `-copyFromLocal` or `-put` to a particular directory or using `-mkdir` you can create new directory

Refer below link for more information

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSCommands.html

Comment: You mean that I should to try to copy files in popeye directory?

Comment: I used "hdfs dfs -ls / " command and I was able to copy files to the directory listed by this command.

Answer (score 2):

If you run:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal foo.txt bar.txt
```

then the local file foo.txt will be copied into your own hdfs directory `/user/popeye/bar.txt` (where `popeye` is your username.) As a result, the following achieves the same:

```
hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal foo.txt /user/popeye/bar.txt
```

Before copying any file into hdfs, just be certain to create the parent directory first. You don't have to put files in this "home" directory, but (1) better to not clutter "/" with all sorts of files, and (2) following this convention will help prevent conflicts with other users.

Answer (score 1):

As per the first answer, I am elaborating it in detailed for `Hadoop 1.x` -

Suppose, you are running this script on pseudo distribution model, you will probably get one or two list of users(NameNodes) illustrated -

on our fully distribution model, first you have the administrator rights to perform these things and there will be N number of list of NameNodes(users).

So now we move to our point -

First reach to your Hadoop home directory and from there run this script -

```
bin/hadoop fs -ls /
```

Result will like this -

```
drwxr-xr-x   - xuiob78126arif supergroup          0 2017-11-30 11:20 /user
```

so here `xuiob78126arif` is my name node(master/user) and the NameNode(user) directory is -

```
/user/xuiob78126arif/
```

now you can go to your browser and search the address -

```
http://xuiob78126arif:50070
```

and from there you can get the `Cluster Summary, NameNode Storage`, etc.

Note : the script will provide results only in one condition, if at least any file or directory exist in DataNode otherwise you will get -

```
ls: Cannot access .: No such file or directory.
```

so, in that case you first put any file by `bin/hadoop fs -put <source file full path>`

and there after run the `bin/hadoop fs -ls /`  script.

and now I hope, you have get a bit on your issue, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To locate HDFS directory and make sure you are drill down to directory where hadoop is installed. If `bin/hadoop fs -ls /` shows no o/p means "/" is hdfs directory. use `mkdir` to create a new dir for map-reduce job [ eg: `hdfs fs -mkdir /user/<local_username>` ]. After this put or `copyfromLocal` commands will work.

I learned this the hardway. I hope someone who is stucked like me finds this helpful